# TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


page=requests.get("http://www.gigantti.fi/catalog/tietokoneet/fi_kannettavat/kannettavat-tietokoneet")

data=BeautifulSoup(page.content)

h=open("test.csv","wb+")
h.write(data)
h.close()

print (data)
```

i have tried running the code as it is without printing it in csv file and it runs perfectly but the moment I try to save it in csv I get the error : argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not BeautifulSoup. PLEASE HELP and thanks in advance

Comment: After looking at the link, I can only assume you're trying to scrape the product info. What you are doing in your snippet does not make sense if that's what you want as you are just saving the whole page as a string(and that too wrongly!). Please refer to [bs4docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for detailed info as to how to find certain elements using identifiers.

Comment: @r3ign sir my apologies if I was unable to explain it clearly. Sir Im trying to scrape the urls from the website but also saving them in a csv file if I didn't convert them in string it was showing an error for format. But I will definitely refer to bs4docs as you suggested. Thank you

Comment: If you need a full video tutorial, follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk) for learning it from scratch.

Comment: @r3ign thank you sir will see those tutorials and if you could suggest please give a link for tutorials regarding django .

Comment: The same channel with the video in the last comment has a django playlist called "Try Django 1.9"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

As mentioned on [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

You do not seem to be pulling any data but you are trying to write a `BeautifulSoup` object into a file which doesn't make sense.

```
>>> type(data)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

What you should be using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for is to search the data for some information, and then use that information, here's a useless example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.gigantti.fi/catalog/tietokoneet/fi_kannettavat/kannettavat-tietokoneet")

data = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
with open("test.txt", "wb+") as f:
   # find the first `<title>` tag and retrieve its value 
   value = data.findAll('title')[0].text
   f.write(value)
```

It seems like you should be using `BeautifulSoup` to be retreiving all the information on each product in the product listing and putting them into columns in a csv file if I'm guessing correctly, but I will leave that work up to you. You must use `BeautifulSoup` to find each product in the `html` and then retrieve all of its details and print to a csv

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether someone was able to solve it or not but my hit and trial worked. the problem was I was not converting the content to string.

```
#what i needed to add was:
#after line data=BeautifulSoup(page.content)
a=str(data)
```

Hopefully this helps